# How do I control transactions in Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working in a Spring Boot project using JPA. I have a scheduled task which I created with the @Scheduled annotation.

This task calls method A, which calls method B. Method B has the @Transactional annotation, and does some work with entities. Unfortunately, method B throws an LazyInitializationException when I try to access a lazily loaded property, claiming "could not initialize proxy - no Session".

I've seen this problem before and solved it by adding the @Transactional annotation to the method, but in this case, the annotation is there and I'm still seeing it.

If I annotate method A with @Transaction, the error disappears. But this isn't what I want. Method A does some long-running work (sending email messages and push notifications) that I don't want to happen inside of the transaction, because that would potentially hold database locks for a long time.

Why can't I limit the transaction just to method B?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Is `B` a public method of a bean? Because otherwise `@Transactional` won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, what are you actually asking here?

- Are you asking how to control transactions and the lifecycle of the persistence context in Hibernate and standard JPA? (As in your question title.)
- Or are you asking how to control transactions in *Spring*.

Because Spring is its own beast.

If you want to know how to do it in standard JPA, the easy answer is that you call `createEntityManager()` to create a persistence context, and `close()` when you want to clean it up.

Or, if you're using standard JPA annotations to inject the `EntityManager` you use:

```java
@PersistenceContext(type=EXTENDED)
EntityManager entityManager;
```

to inject an extended persistence context. And then the lifetime of that PC ends up being determined by the lifetime of the bean it's injected into, as defined by EJB or CDI or whatever.

But of course Spring does not follow the JPA specification, nor the CDI standard, and does everything in its own way. (Unlike Hibernate, which embraces the standard, Spring has a long history of rejecting standards.)

Answer (score 0):

Annotating the method of `B` should work if `B` is a bean (i.e. it gets injected by Spring and not instantiated by your code and the method is public.

If you don't want to change how `B` gets constructed or the visibility of its method you may use a [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) to explicitly control transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. I have a better understanding of this now. I don’t think annotations work if you call a method from another method in the same class.

I fixed it by having my top level method call A and B separately instead of having A call B. It worked in this case but I’m looking forward to using TransactionTemplate next time.

I did a lot of work in Hibernate many years ago (2005) and probably understood this at the time but forgot. In the interim I’ve mostly been using my own frameworks on top of JDBC.

Frank